# Contract matching rules are being ignored when running verification

Tags: pact

The matching rules in my contract are being ignored. I have a contract where I need to make sure that certain value is a string. When running verify command I am getting an error because the test is looking for an exact match. I am using in the consumer side (javascript) pact Matchers in order to check only for the type of data and not the value itself. The provider is a rails application using pact version 1.20.0.

I also tried to use regex but the problem is still happening.

This is how the contract looks. 
I have removed some sensitive data.

```
{
  "consumer": {
    "name": "consumer"
  },
  "provider": {
    "name": "provider"
  },
  "interactions": [
    {
      "description": "a request",
      "providerState": "provider state",
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "path": "/path/api/stuff",
        "headers": {
          "Authorization": "Bearer token",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        "body": {
          "source_code": "abcdef"
        },
        "matchingRules": {
          "$.body": {
            "match": "type"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "pactSpecification": {
      "version": "3.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

This is the error that I am getting.

```
   Diff
   --------------------------------------
   Key: - is expected 
        + is actual 
   Matching keys and values are not shown

    {
   -  "source_code": "abcdef"
   +  "source_code": "xde5r8"
    }

   Description of differences
   --------------------------------------
   * Expected "abcdef" but got "xde5e3" at $.source_code
```

I expect this test to be successful because I am expecting a match in the type, and in this case both responses are strings. Maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: Could you please add some more context to your question such as the consumer and provider language, or ideally, some code / gists to look at to help?

Comment: Your assumption was correct. The problem was the pactSpecification. I changed the version from 3.0.0 to 2.0.0 by hand in the contract and the test passed. In the consumer side I am using javascript "@pact-foundation/pact": "8.2.0". and in the provider side which is in rails 'pact', '1.20.1' . Is there a way that can I make these two match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks to be a v3 body matcher, which not all language implementations share (see [1]). It's possible that you're using a consumer language (e.g. Pact JVM) that is generating a v3 contract, but is being verified by a v2 provider (e.g. Pact JS).

- [1] https://docs.pact.io/feature_support